# Is there a function to read value in cell, whose row specified by value in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns, `B`(freq) and `C`(AvgValue), I want to find the corresponding freq(column B) for the largest AvgValue(column C) in the first 300 cells.
I used match method as `D1=MATCH(MAX(C1:C300),C1:C300,0)` and returns the row of the largest AvgValue, the value is 260. Now I can use `E1=B260` to find the freq, but failed to use `E1=B(D1)`. I also searched methods like `=indirect()` but not succeeded. Thank you!

```
0.101393946 8.75E-01
0.102807322 8.75E-01
0.104240401 8.76E-01
0.105693455 8.77E-01
0.107166765 8.79E-01
0.108660611 8.80E-01
0.110175281 8.81E-01
0.111711065 8.79E-01
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the input data in the range: `A1:B10`, then you can get the result combining `INDEX` and `XMATCH` as follow:

```
=INDEX(B1:B10, XMATCH(MAX(A1:A10), A1:A10))
```

[image: Excel output]

**Note**: If the column `A` has more than one value with max value then you may want to concatenate the frequency values that correspond to max value as follow: `=TEXTJOIN(",", ,FILTER(B1:B10, A1:A10=MAX(A1:A10)))`. Otherwise the previous approach (`INDEX/XMATCH`) returns the frequency of the first maximum value found.

Comment: Thank you so much David!
I see the answer is accepted (though I was late to do that)

Comment: Thanks, @Rookie, just to let you know I don't see the answer accepted or voted. Thanks